# Cannot display images using spring

Tags: spring-boot

Screenshots:

[image: code screenshot]

[image: page screenshot]

I followed the code in spring in action but it does not work out, did I do something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to...</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/taco.jpg}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*. Why did you think we'd want a *picture*?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I posted the html code.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely entered a wrong image path.
Try using `/resources/static/images/taco.jpg`.
If that doesn't work experiment with the paths.